# XML (wsdl) How to inline included and/or imported Schemas (XSDs)

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I was given the task to create a simple (java)program which takes an xml-file (a wsdl) and inlines includes and imports. So you get one big AllInOne-File.
In the wsdl:types Element there is the following:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <!-- In Produktion ist ein absoluter Pfad zu verwenden. -->
        <xsd:import namespace="http://namepsace.net/namespace"
            schemaLocation="transfer-object.xsd" />
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Here I can just replace the xsd:schema element with the content of the xsd.

When the inlined Schema has includes I can just replace the Include-Tag with the content of the included Schema?!

My Problem: When the importet or included Schema has imports like:

```
   <import  namespace="http://differentNamespace" schemaLocation="schema.xsd" />
```

how can I inline this?

I searched for a free and simple to use tool/software to inline schemas but didn't found anything. I'm glad for any suggestions regarding my problem or providing an idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inline imports. Schema components for different namespaces need to be defined in different modules; there's no way to create a single schema document that contains components having multiple target namespaces.